# JQuery Multiple Append Only Appends Last one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jQuery to create a table. Currently I have an empty table body and I would like to use some jQuery to fill up the table:

```js
var $tr = $("<tr>"),
  $td = $("<td>");
var date = '2018-01-01'
$td.text(date);
$tr.append($td);

$td.text("New Years");
$tr.append($td);

$("#body").append($tr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id='body'>

  </tbody>
  <table>
```

But this only appends the second `td`. The first one gets overwritten. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Append does not clone elements.  If an element is already attached to the dom (or a dom fragment), it will detach it and put it in the new place.  An element can only have a single direct parent in the DOM.  You could circumvent this by appending `$td.prop('outerHtml')`, or make different td elements when you append

Comment: Perhaps this link might assist you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Taplar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586174/taplar) said in comments, if the element already is in DOM, the `.append` will only "move it".

Now in your example, you append it a the same place, but also change the text.

Try the [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method to duplicate elements.

```js
var $tr = $("<tr>");
var $td = $("<td>");
var date = '2018-01-01';

$td.text(date);
$tr.append($td);

var secondCell = $td.clone().text("New Years");
$tr.append(secondCell);

$("#body").append($tr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id='body'>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $tr1 = $("<tr>"),
  $tr2 = $("<tr>"),
  $tr3 = $("<tr>"),
  $td = $("<td>");
var date = '2018-01-01';

$td.text(date);

//various ways to accomplish it
$tr1.append($td.prop('outerHTML'));
$tr2.append($td.clone());
$tr3.append($('<td>', { text: date }));

$td.text("New Years");
$tr1.append($td.prop('outerHTML'));
$tr2.append($td.clone());
$tr3.append($('<td>', { text: 'New Years' }));

$("#body").append([$tr1, $tr2, $tr3]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id='body'>

  </tbody>
  <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone $td, so that DOM treats it as a new element.

```js
var $tr = $("<tr>"),
  $td = $("<td>");
var date = '2018-01-01'
$td.text(date);
$tr.append($td.clone());

$td.text("New Years");
$tr.append($td.clone());

$("#body").append($tr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id='body'>

  </tbody>
  <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try next code without jquery:

```
let tbody =  document.querySelector('#body');
let tr =  document.createElement('tr');
let td = document.createElement('tr');
td.textContent = '2018-01-01';;
let tdClone = td.cloneNode();
tdClone.textContent = "New Years";
tr.append(td,tdClone);
tbody.append(tr);
```

I think that is true way, because you can create  new td instead of clone created td (maybe for example this td has special classes or atributes), and you code repaint DOM only after insert tr in table.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Maybe this could be an alternative to do that:

```
var texts = ["2018-01-01", "New Years"];

$.each(texts, function(i, val){
    $("<tr><td>"+val+"</td></tr>").appendTo("#body")
});
```

`$.each` gets each item on the array `texts`, wrap it on `tr` and `td`, then append to the result on `#body`.

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ericgruby/b7j20fmg/)